# Can I dynamically modify link characteristics during a Mininet emulation?

Tags: python-2.7, mininet

I am currently emulating a simple network on Mininet using the Python API available, with help from several internet tutorials and other sources. Current network emulations in Mininet support link modifications only using the *configLinkStatus()* method under the class *Mininet*.
This permits only 2 states:- *up* and *down*
Other characteristics like propagation delay, bandwidth, and bit error rate can only be set during the addition of a link.
My problem contains switches and hosts in motion, which in turn causes dynamic changes in the link state. Is there a solution in Mininet to modify the links to fit my requirements?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem recently and tried many solutions on the internet, but none of them worked fine. At last with some try and error, below code worked for me.

```
def changeBandwith( node ):
  for intf in node.intfList(): # loop on interfaces of node
    #info( ' %s:'%intf )
    if intf.link: # get link that connects to interface(if any)
        newBW = 5
        intfs = [ intf.link.intf1, intf.link.intf2 ] #intfs[0] is source of link and intfs[1] is dst of link
        intfs[0].config(bw=newBW) 
        intfs[1].config(bw=newBW)
    else:
        info( ' \n' )

def manageLinks():
    nodes = net.switches + net.hosts
    for node in nodes:
        changeBandwith(node)
```

as mininet api explains about config function(check at this [link](http://mininet.org/api/classmininet_1_1link_1_1TCIntf.html#a4e9cf4cb9e39771a537fa4ec717bd0a4)), you can modify bandwidth, delay and other link properties with this function.

hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
You have several methods that can help you with that:

- getNodeByName(node) - returns a node object by its id. This is a method of the Mininet class.
- connectionsTo(dst) - This is a method of the node class. Returns a list of links from the source node object to *destination* node.

So, for example if you want to delete alink from h1 to h2 (assuming net is the Mininet object):

```
h1 = net.getNodeByName('h1') 
h2 = net.getNodeByName('h2') 

links = h1.connectionsTo(h2)
del links[int(index)]
```

where index would be the link number that you want to delete (in case you have more than one link between nodes).

For adding links, you use the addLink method of the Mininet class.

With the help of those methods, you can delete and re-create a link with new parameters.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. You're modifying the topology not the link.